# What heuristic cost is correct? Why my is incorrect? Finding optimal path on graph

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, a-star

I have simple graph and I need to find heuristic costs for this graph.

Graph is (matrix representation):

```
0 1 2 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 3 3 2 0
3 0 0 2 0 0 0
0 3 1 0 1 0 0
0 3 0 1 0 6 0
0 2 0 0 6 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 2 0
```

Image:

[image: graph]

Values in brackets means heuristic costs of the vertex for current goal vertex.

Green vertex is start and red vertex is goal.

I created this heristic costs matrix:

```
0 2 6 3 1 9 5
9 0 2 4 6 4 1
1 3 0 5 2 9 4
3 1 5 0 1 7 8
0 6 2 1 0 10 14
2 1 6 3 7 0 5
1 4 3 2 1 3 0
```

I have to explain this. This matrix represents this: for example goal vertex is 7; we find 7th row in matrix; value in 1st col means heuristic cost from 1 vertex to 7 vertex (7 is goal); value in 5nd col means heurisitc cost from 5 vertex to 7 vertex (7 is goal); if 5 is goal, we will work with 5 row, etc...

This heusristic costs based on nothing. I don't know how to find good heuristic costs. That is the question.

To summarize:

Firstly, my algorithm found wrong path (because of wrong heuristics probably). It found 1-3-4-5 (length 5), but best is 1-2-5 (length 4).

Also, teacher said, that my heuristic costs prevents the algorithm to find good path, but not helps him. I have problems with translating what he said into english, but he said somethink like: "your heuristic mustn't overestimate best path". What does it mean?

So the question: how to find good heuristic costs in my case?

Comment: A* requires the heuristic to underestimate the cost of the shortest path or it may produce suboptimal results. That said, for such a simple graph you don't need A* at all, you can just run an all-pairs shortest path algorithm.

Comment: @larsmans, but I have task to use A*. It is just lab :). I can't say, that it is stupid to use A* here. All understand this. They just want understanding of how A* works from me. What `A* requires the heuristic to underestimate the cost of the shortest path or it may produce suboptimal results` means on practic? CAn you provide an example?

Comment: ~ same wrote at the wiki. Maybe it is some language barrier... but I don't understand what it means. Can you provide an example?

Comment: You already have the example, your code returns a suboptimal path. See any good AI textbook for why this happens, e.g. [AIMA](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/).

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Do you have any knowledge on the graph? What is it representing? Without any knowledge, the only admissible heuristic you can use is `h(v) = 0`, for all `v in V`. A* benefits from being an informed algorithm. But if you have no extra information, it cannot be informed - and its benefit is basically gone.

Comment: @Amit It is representing nothing. Arrgh :) Is my english is succchhhh bad?? It is just and example. Lets say it is representing something. It is not distance in meters etc :) I have to use heuristic anyway. I understand, that it is stupid in REAL task, but it is just an example. Also, I understand that it might be stupid, but some teachers in my University wants this. I just need to pass it and thats all :)

Comment: @SharikovVladislav Then the only heurisric you can actually find that is also admissible is `h(v)=0`. Note that A* in this case will behave like Dijkstra's Algorithm.

Comment: @amit ?!!! Why we can't just imagine, that this graph represents something? Lets forget about this part. What means `overestimate best path`? How to make heuristic cost to not `overestimate best path`?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav "overestimate best path" means that your shortest path from some node `v` to the goal is of length `k`, but `h(v)=k'` such that `k'>k`. In this case, the heuristic is overestimating the length of the path. A heuristic that does it for 1 or more nodes is called "inadmissible", and A* is not guaranteed to find the shortest path with such a heuristic. If you choose `h(v)=0` for all v, you are guaranteed your A* is never overestimating, and if you have no knowledge on the graph - this is the only admissible heuristic you can use.

Comment: The matrix representation of the graph contains two errors.

Comment: @amit thank you, I will try to do something tomorrow

Comment: @user3386109 Possible, that I mixed up old and new matrix/image. Sorry.

Comment: @amit Actually there is a set of better heuristics, one which is the all-pairs shortest path cost. With that heuristic, A* can just march toward the goal. Any underestimate of the shortest path cost is also a valid heuristic.

Comment: @larsmans Yes, but finding this heuristic (which is basically h^*) requires more computation time than running A* with h(v)=0. Also, unless you use some tie breaker, even using `h^*` does not guarantee going directly to the goal, like discussed in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23084264/572670)

Comment: @larsmans Every heuristic (except some local optimization like `h(v) = (v is target? 0 : MIN_WEIGHT)`) will need not actually find the shortest path in order to be used, which is not quite optimal..

Comment: @amit The all-pairs shortest paths can be computed offline so evaluating the heuristic is just table-lookup.

Comment: @larsmans If you have all-pairs shortest paths the shortest path is given by d(v,u) - there is no reason to use A* or dijkstra once you have it.

Comment: @larsmans On the other hand, you could use unweighted shortest path from all nodes to the target in O(V+E), get the `uwd(v)` (unweighted distance) per node, and use the heuristic `h(v) = uwd(v) * MIN_WEIGHT`, where MIN_WEIGHT is the smallest edge weight in the grap (and is easily found).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to wrap my comments as an answer.

First, note that "overestimate best path" means that your shortest path from some node v to the goal is of length `k`, but `h(v)=k'` such that `k'>k`. In this case, the heuristic is overestimating the length of the path. A heuristic that does it for 1 or more nodes is called "inadmissible", and A* is not guaranteed to find the shortest path with such a heuristic.

[An admissible heuristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) (never overestimating) is guaranteed to provide the optimal path for A*.
The simplest admissible heuristic is h(v) = 0 for all `v`. Note that in this case, A* will actually behave like [Dijsktra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (which is basically an uniformed A*).

You can find more informative heuristics, one example is to first pre-process the graph and find the shortest **unweighted** path from each node to the goal. This can be done efficiently by [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Denote this unweighted distance from some `v` to the goal as `uwd(v)`.

Now, you can create a heuristic which is `uwd(v) * MIN_WEIGHT`, where `MIN_WEIGHT` is the smallest edge weight in the graph.

Comment: It is work for only shortest path? I mean... I have 5 vertexes. I want to find path from 1 to 5. For 1 to 5 best length is `l`, `h(1) = l'` and `l'>l` — heuristic cost overestimating path from 1 to 5. For example shortest path going through 2. Now about 2 to 5 path. Best path from 2 to 5 is `d`. `h(2) = d'`, `d'>d` path from 2 to 5 overestimated by heuristic cost `h(2)`, rigth? Or for `2` vertex rule is `d' > l`? `h(2)` heurisitc cost greater then `l` — path from start to goal.

Comment: Hope, you will understand me :)

Comment: Will heuristic cost `h(v)` overestimate path (length `k`) from `v` to goal if `h(v) = k'` and `k = k'`?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav I did not understand your first comment. If `h(v) = k'` and shortest path is of length `k`, and `k=k'` - this is not an overestimation.